# How to change entries of Array of Objects with another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm quite new to JS, so excuse me if the question is overly complicated and probably a duplicate, but this problem bugged me for quite some time now and I couldn't find a satisfying answer or solution.

I have an array of Objects, where I want to change some properties based on another array of the same length. I thought this would be easily done in a for-loop, but to my surprise all properties end up having the same value.

Here is the array of Objects (`dattmp`) and the other array (`color`):

```
var testdat = {
    Element1: {time: [1586777601886.39, 1586777608597.8, 1586777615309.21]},
    Element2: {time: [1586777603886.39, 1586777638597.8, 1586777315309.21]}
}
var options = {pathOptions: {className: "myclass"}}

var dattmp = [];
for (kys in testdat) {
    var tmp = {
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {
          time: testdat[kys].time,
          path_options: options.pathOptions
      }
    };
    dattmp.push(tmp);
}

var color = ["orange", "blue"];
```

My goal is to include the color in `dattmp`, so that the first Objects color is orange and the second one blue.

I tried a normal `for-loop` and a `map` but both color properties end up being `blue`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
    dattmp[i].properties.path_options.color = color[i];
}

const newdat = dattmp.map((dt, i)  => {
    dt.properties.path_options.color = color[i];
    return dt;
});
```

The following would work, but my IDE tells me there are a lot of problems with this code, and I don't really understand the `...` notation. So my question is: **What is the correct approach to changing the values individually?**

```
const newdat1 = dattmp.map((dt, i)  => {
    dt = { ...dt, properties: {...dt.properties, path_options: {...dt.properties.path_options, color: color[i]}}};
    return dt;
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is `options.pathOptions` refer to thee same object in both elements of the array. Since it's just a reference, modifying it modifies it on all elements of the array. To copy , try [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var testdat = {
  Element1: { time: [1586777601886.39, 1586777608597.8, 1586777615309.21] },
  Element2: { time: [1586777603886.39, 1586777638597.8, 1586777315309.21] },
};
var options = { pathOptions: { className: 'myclass' } };

var dattmp = [];
for (kys in testdat) {
  var tmp = {
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {
      time: testdat[kys].time,
      path_options: Object.assign({}, options.pathOptions),
    },
  };
  dattmp.push(tmp);
}
var color = ['orange', 'blue'];

for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
  dattmp[i].properties.path_options.color = color[i];
}
console.log(dattmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```
const dattmp = [];


const color = ["orange", "blue"];

for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i += 1) {
  const obj = {
    properties: {
      path_options: {
        color: color[i],
      },
    },
  };
  dattmp.push(obj);
}
```

The problem is that you're trying to read properties from an empty array.

Edit: If you want to preserve other properties, you can use this:

```
const newdat1 = dattmp.map((dt, i) => {
  const obj = {
    ...dt,
    properties: {
      ...dt.properties,
      path_options: { ...dt.properties.path_options, color: color[i] },
    },
  };
  return obj;
});
```

Comment: But I want to keep the other properties type, time etc and just add/change the color property.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I am using right now. Is that really the most elegant way to change a property?

Comment: @SeGa I don't really know what your use case is. but I don't think there is any neater way for what you want to achieve.